# SAPUI5 How to clear combobox selection when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a combobox that due to its nature it initializes without any item selected (figure 1). When I select an item, the selection is set (figure 2). Then, I have a button that when pressed it should make that combobox back to the first state, without any selection visible, "blank" basically (figure 1).

How can I get the button back to it's initial stage when a button is pressed?

[image: figure 1] figure 1

[image: figure 2] figure 2

Answer (score 2):

try using smth like this in ur onPressButton function:

this.getView().byId("urComboBoxID").setValue(null)

it should now be initial

Answer (score 0):

When button is pressed you can write in your controller:

```
var oComboBox = this.getView().byId("yourComboBoxId");
oComboBox.setSelectedKey("A");
```

And you can define key in you xml file:

```
<ComboBox id="yourComboBoxId" selectedKey="A" width="150px">
   <core:Item text="" key="A"  />
   <core:Item text="B" key="B" />
   <core:Item text="C" key="C" />
   <core:Item text="D" key="D" />
</ComboBox>
```

EDITED 16:14 240217:

[Example](http://jsbin.com/behizaceqi/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Yeah, I tried that before but it adds a blank item which does not look good.

Comment: And what do you want to get if not blank?

Comment: That is becomes blank without adding a blank item.

Comment: So you can use method setValue(null) http://jsbin.com/jukogakota/1/edit?html,js,output, what @Eric Schuster proposed.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
_YourCombobox.setSelectedKey("");
```